# Efficient table structure or indexing for searchable IP address ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, performance, range, ip-address

I have raw data provided to me for a geolocation service, in the form of a table of IP address ranges mapped to location data.

The addresses are provided as byte-packed integers (one dotted-quad per byte), permitting easy storage and comparisons, so each row in this table provides a range low address, a range high address, and some text location fields. I don't have to/am not able to use CIDR.

The table is several million records.

I don't have strong SQL chops. The code I inherited simply does a sql call like:

```
SELECT location FROM geodata WHERE lookup_address >= range_low AND lookup_address =< range_high
```

The performance is terrible. My understanding is that this will simply do a linear search for matching records. To get around this temporarily I have thrown together a client cache into a tree map to bring this down to log performance, but a) my memory usage is now hard to justify, and b) detecting live database updates is a problem I don't really want to tackle right now.

It seems like this problem must come up now and then in the SQL world for addresses, telephone numbers, etc.. Is there a "standard" way to organize and index ranges in a SQL table so that I can get at least log performance out of a direct SQL query?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  Some of them offer special data types that calculate this correctly...

Comment: Happens to be MS 2008, but I'm not able to rely on that.

Comment: Are the IP ranges guaranteed to be in a specific format - if so what format?  Can you modify the table to split the address sublevels out to separate columns?

Comment: IP addresses are byte packed (e.g, 192.168.0.1 is stored as C0A80001 = 3232235521), so I can treat them as simple integers when comparing whether an address is within a range. Seems to be the way most geolocation/geoIP vendors like MaxMind are supporting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have index on your filter fields - in this case `range_low` and `range_high`.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_geodata_range_fields ON geodata (range_low, range_high)
```

Comment: I think the data got a bit flipped. The lookup_address is the input, and will essentially be a random IP address, so I'm pretty sure an ALTER TABLE is not desirable on each request.

Comment: @MattThompson: I'm not sure you're following what this code does.  First, it creates several calculated fields on the table (a one-time task) based on the values held in `lookup_address`  The calculated fields hold the different potential submasks for the corresponding lookup_address for efficient lookup.  Then it creates an index on these fields (again, a one-time task).  The index will update itself as the data in lookup_address is added or modified.  Lastly, you can run the SELECT statement as many times as you wish, passing in a low and high range.

Comment: And before you go off and do any of this, you did try adding a simple index on the `lookup_address` field, right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling with my understanding of SQL indexes. What I have is a large list of address ranges, like 10.1.10.0 - 10.1.20.0 = USA. I will have several million entries like that during initialization. Then I am asked during runtime, for, say, 10.1.10.2, which country am I in? Then after I have figured that out, I am asked for some other random address, then another, then another. I know nothing about the input, the "lookup_address", other than it will be a valid IP address. I'm not sure I can apply your index scheme against both range_low and range_high to speed up those searches.

Comment: Ah, that's the gap. lookup_address is the search term, not the information stored in the database.

Comment: @MattThompson: Indeed that's the gap - sorry about that!  So what are range_low and range_high?  And are you expecting a single record to match this for a search term, or multiple records?  Lastly, did you try creating an index that includes range_low and range_high?  Updated to reflect this.